# How do I remove a node in xml using ElementTree in Python?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I've read the `remove` example [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) and the example [here](http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm) is not applicable to me.

My xml file reads:

```
<A>
  <B>some text</B>
  <B>other text</B>
  <B>more text</B>
</A>
```

What I want to do is to remove the second `<B></B>` from the xml. I do not know what text it holds. But I have the index of the `<B></B>`, say index = 1, which means I want to remove the second element (or node).

I have a code like this:

```
F = open('example.xml')
self.tree = parse(F)
self.root = self.tree.getroot()
F.close()
```

So in this case what I want to remove is `self.root[1]`.

How can this be implemented using ElementTree?

Edit: Made my question more clear and specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
In [1]: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

In [2]: xmlstr=\
   ...: """
   ...: <A>
   ...:   <B>some text</B>
   ...:   <B>other text</B>
   ...:   <B>more text</B>
   ...: </A>
   ...: """

In [3]: tree=ET.fromstring(xmlstr)

In [4]: tree.remove(tree.findall('.//B')[1])
```

Comment: I had to replace `tree.` with `tree.getroot().` for this to work

Answer (score 3):

You guys are not straight to the point. I've combined my knowledge with the answers here and came out with this:

```
for i, child in enumerate(self.root):
    if path == i:
        self.root.remove(child)
        break
```

where `path` is the index of the item I want to remove.

Comment: @ elwz -- and how is that better than `tree.remove(tree.findall('.//B')[1])` ?

Comment: My apologies. It did work now. Just that I was confused about tree and root (originally in the question). I'll give you the honor.