# How do I remove last sibling nodes with the same tag?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

I am having trouble removing some elements using xml.etree.ElementTree.  I have found a similar situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051422/how-do-i-remove-a-node-in-xml-using-elementtree-in-python) but it does not solve my problem.  I have also read docs on [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.remove) and [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).

I have an xml tree resembling this

```
<metadata>
    <lineage>
        <srcinfo></srcinfo>
        <procstep>
            <otherinfo></otherinfo>
        </procstep>
        <procstep>
            <otherinfo></otherinfo>
        </procstep>
        <procstep>
            <otherinfo></otherinfo>
        </procstep>
        <procstep>
            <otherinfo></otherinfo>
        </procstep>
    </lineage>
</metadata>
```

Suppose I wanted to remove the second, third, and fourth procstep elements.  I have tried the following code with the result of a "ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list" error.

```
while len(root.findall('.//lineage/procstep')) > 1:
        root.remove(root.findall('.//lineage/procstep[last()]'))
```

Any suggestions as to why this does not work?  Are there other approaches to my problem?  Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Remove the last procstep

To remove `procstep` element, use procstep's parent (`lineage`).

Try:

```
lineage = root.find('.//lineage')
last_procstep = lineage.find('./procstep[last()]')
lineage.remove(last_procstep)
```

If you use lxml, you can use `getparent()` as follow:

```
last_procstep = root.find('.//lineage/procstep[last()]')
last_procstep.getparent().remove(last_procstep)
```

### Remove procstep elements but the first

```
lineage = root.find('.//lineage')
for procstep in tuple(lineage.iterfind('./procstep'))[1:]:
    lineage.remove(procstep)
```

Comment: Thanks falsetru, that works to remove the last element.  How would you remove all but the first procstep element?

Comment: @Barbarossa, use `.//lineage/procstep[position()>1]`.

Comment: thank you but it does not solve my problem.  I have seen the use of lxml, but I am using ElementTree.  Is there way to do what I am asking with what I have?  The [position] predicate is unsupported in ElementTree I believe

Comment: @Barbarossa, The first code in my answer is work both in ElementTree and lxml.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Sorry for the confusion.  Thanks again.