# Strange behavior of lxml's etree iterator

Tags: python, iterator, lxml

Task is - while iterating over xml tree delete 'current' node, save xml document and feed it to 3rd party application. Depending on the result bring this node back to the tree or just forget about it.

Let me demonstrate the oddity:

```
<test>
  <A>
    <A1>
      <A2>A2</A2>
    </A1>
  </A>
  <B>
    <B1>B1</B1>
  </B>
  <C>C</C>
</test>
```

Here's the python code:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

tree = ET.parse('t.xml')

delete = False

def print_tree():
    print '*' * 5
    for node in tree.getiterator():
        print node.tag
    print '*' * 5

print_tree()

for node in tree.getiterator():
    #delete the first node (<A> in our case)
    if not delete:
        try:
            node.getparent().remove(node)
            delete = True
        except:
            pass

    print '* ' + node.tag

print_tree()
```

The output will be like that:

```
*****
test
A
A1
A2
B
B1
C
***** <-- these are all elements iterator can reach
* test
* A
* A1
* A2
*****
test
B
B1
C
*****
```

As you can see after removing a node the iterator goes only to A-branch.

How can I make it to cover the rest of the tree? I would appreciate a more elegant solution.

Comment: Is your xml very big? I think its not advised to try to change the structure of xml while iterating over it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is more than one problem with your code or environment.

When I run your code (Windows 7x64 32-bit python 2.7.8) I get the following (different from yours) output:

```
*****
test
A
A1
A2
B
B1
C
*****
* test
* A
* A1
* A2
*****
test
B
B1
C
*****
```

So this first problem  of me getting different output from you is likely due to environment - yours or mine. What version of python are you using?

Your question was why doesn't the iterator go into the B part of the tree? Well, looking at your delete code, it deletes the current node then you are assuming the iterator will carry on iterating further into and over the rest of the tree - i.e. you're modifying the tree at the point you're currently on. That's likely to confuse the iterator, and it is doing.

AFAICT the description of the remove() method says 'Removes subelement from the element'. You are trying to use remove to remove 'the element', which is like sitting on the end of a branch and sawing through it nearer the trunk.

Assuming you just want to delete the A node using an iterator, this works (note the break - no point in iterating further) (also note the absence of the try/except):

```
for node in tree.getiterator():
    #delete the first <A> subelement
    Anode = node.find("A")
    if Anode is not None:
        node.remove(Anode)
        break
```

The other problem is probably with your code. Your except statement containing just 'pass' is suppressing an exception - that's a very dodgy thing to do. The cause of the exception in my environment is that the first time into the for loop, i.e. on the root node test, the call to getparent() is correctly returning None, and that can't be removed. Suppressing all exceptions like this isn't a robust solution to that problem, because it also suppresses any other errors, and anyway means there is probably a logical error in your code.

HTH
barny

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer. Two things: the diffirence in output is because I edited the post and didn't fix everything (now everything should be fine). Secondly - actually I want to try to delete every one node in the document, so find-and-remove trick won't work. As far as I understood - to keep iterator running I can saw the next branch, but not the one I (iterator) is currently sitting  on?

Comment: Deleting/modifying in an iterator is likely to be risky. If you want to delete all nodes, why not just create a new empty tree? Or search stackoverflow, look at examples in answers like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051422/how-do-i-remove-a-node-in-xml-using-elementtree-in-python

Comment: I meant I'm going to delete them one by one (some of them will stay eventually). Found that guy over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419754/how-to-remove-a-node-inside-an-iterator-in-python-xml-etree-elementree wanted to do pretty the same thing and it seems for him this approach worked well. I just realized he didn't need alive iterator, forget it.